# How to wait for a Function to return values and finish to run another Function with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

As the thread's title, this worked well with the demo below. However, when I'd tried to get the information from another link (it must be another thread of SharePoint). Thus, that code didn't work anymore.

---

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/yh755/)**</kbd>

Result:

- a done
- b done
- FunctionTwo

---

**My Javascript as my current problem:**

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
  var
a = $.Deferred(),
b = $.Deferred();

  // some fake asyc task
  // Get information from another site
   var set_current_login_name = currentUser.get_title(); //The code to get information goes here 
   alert(set_current_login_name); // Result: "Transportation"
   a.resolve();

  // some other fake asyc task
  alert('b done');
  b.resolve();

  return $.Deferred(function (def) {
  $.when(a, b).done(function () {
  def.resolve();
      });
  });
};

var FunctionTwo = function () {
    alert('FunctionTwo');
};

FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo);
```

Result:

- b done
- FunctionTwo
- Transportation

**The Result must be like this:**

- Transportation
- b done
- FunctionTwo

Comment: You have to provide a better example. The two `alert` statements are in the same environment and this means the first `alert` will appear before the second one.

Comment: **@FelixKling**: I just edited my code as `var set_current_login_name = currentUser.get_title(); //The code to get information goes here `

Comment: That doesn't really make a difference though.

Comment: **@FelixKling**: This is the SharePoint's thread, I am looking for any help that how to wait for that thread finished and then continue to run the others...